# Numpy shuffling with selective condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to shuffle a 2d Numpy array with a condition. For example only shuffle non-zero values.

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
a[2,2] = 0

# Shuffle non-zero values 

# Example shuffle with only 0 staying in place
>>> a
array([[0, 5, 3],
       [7, 2, 6],
       [4, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Should the initial and shuffled arrays have the same elements?

Comment: Yes – scrambling of all values but the ones which fulfil the condition.

Comment: Check @Brenlla 's comment on my answer, you should be accepting another answer, there is an error I did not take into account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do that:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
a[2,2] = 0

# Take a flattened version of the array
b = a.flatten()  # If you do not need a copy use a.ravel()
# Find indices of non-zero values
idx, = np.nonzero(b)
# Shuffle those indices
b[idx] = b[np.random.permutation(idx)]
# Put back into original shape
b = b.reshape(a.shape)
print(b)
# [[0 7 3]
#  [2 4 1]
#  [6 5 0]]
```

If you want to use a different condition, just replace:

```
idx, = np.nonzero(b)
```

With:

```
idx, = np.where(condition)
```

For example, to shuffle only even numbers, you would use `b % 2 == 0` as `condition`.

Answer (score 4):

you could do :

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
a[2,2] = 0
c = a[a!=0]
np.random.shuffle(c)
a[a!=0] = c
a 
#  array([[0, 6, 5],
#         [2, 3, 7],
#         [4, 1, 0]])
```

and if you have a different condition , you could just do :

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
a[2,2] = 0
cond = a>3
c = a[cond]
np.random.shuffle(c)
a[cond] = c
```

A more concise way would be :

```py
a = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
a[2,2] = 0
a[a>3] = np.random.permutation(a[a>3])
```